# I want a download that acts like a proxy

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my users to download a file say **file.zip**

from

```
 www.remoteurl/file.zip
```

but the file should be downloaded from

```
 www.mydomain.com/file.zip
```

I want my server to act as a proxy which will change the remote url to mydomain. (Note: the file shouldn't be downloaded to my server.)

Can you suggest a good approach for this, or is there even a finished script for this purpose ?

Comment: Still there @Abhicenation ?

Comment: yes @PedroLobito ....

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, still, I think you want users to think they're downloading a file from your server while in fact the download is located on a remote server. If my assumption is correct, there are many ways to achieve that, here's one:

Let's say the user clicks on a link that contains:

http://www.yousite.com/myfiles/file.zip

First, we use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to forward any requests to  `myfiles` to our phpscript (`download.php`).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myfiles/(.*)$ /download.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

---

Now we can `$_GET` the value of `file` inside **`download.php`**

**download.php**

```
if(!EMPTY($_GET['file'])){

$url = 'http://www.remoteurl.com/'.$_GET['file'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url);
$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];
header("Content-type: application/$ext");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo file_get_contents($url);

}
```

---

You might want to restrict the downloads based on the file extension, for that you can use:

```
if (!EMPTY($_GET['file']) && preg_match('/\.(zip|txt|rar|tar|gz)$/', $_GET['file'])) {
//the rest of the code...
```

Comment: yes your assumption is correct i want same like this .